# ScrollMagic on Enter not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

I'm using ScrollMagic, the following code:

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: slides[i]
        })
    .setPin(slides[i])
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller)
    .triggerHook(0.10)
    .on('enter', function(e){
        panel = $(e.target.triggerElement()).prop('id');
        $('.circle').removeClass('active');
        $('.circle.c-'+panel).addClass('active');
    });
```

The on enter function works perfectly when scrolling down but not when scrolling up.
Accordying the official documentation it works both ways, what may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `reverse` to `true` like so:

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: slides[i]
        })
    .setPin(slides[i])
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller)
    .triggerHook(0.10)
    .reverse(true)
    .on('enter', function(e){
        panel = $(e.target.triggerElement()).prop('id');
        $('.circle').removeClass('active');
        $('.circle.c-'+panel).addClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write on "leave" function,

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
triggerElement: slides[i]
    })
.setPin(slides[i])
.addIndicators()
.addTo(controller)
.triggerHook(0.10)
.on('enter', function(e){
    panel = $(e.target.triggerElement()).prop('id');
    $('.circle').removeClass('active');
    $('.circle.c-'+panel).addClass('active');
})
.on('leave', function(e){
    // Your up scroll code here.
});
```